# swiftで画面横向きにした場合にnavigationバーを消したい

Tags: swift, navigationbar

swiftで画面横向きにした場合にnavigationバーを消したい（非表示）にしたいと思っています。

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        // 現在のデバイスの向きを取得.
        let deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation!  = UIDevice.current.orientation

        // 向きの判定.
        if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) {
            print("横向き")
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)            
            PlayerView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height:size.height)
        } else if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation){
            print("縦向き")
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
            PlayerView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:size.width, height:size.height)
        }
    }
```

としていますが、画面横向きにすると
[image: 横画面スクリーンショット]
のように画面上部に白い帯が残ります（PlayerViewはわかりやすく灰色にしています）。
Navigationbarには「<戻る」だけが消えているだけの状況です。

この帯も消す（非表示）にするにはどうしたいいのでしょうか？

(自己解決)
Storyboard上のconstraintsが効いていました。constraintsを削除してやりたいことが実現できました。

Comment: 白い帯が残る、というよりは、(x:0, y:0) がその位置なのではないでしょうか？試しに(x:0, y:-44)に表示してみると想定通りに動きませんか？（推奨される方法ではありませんが）

Comment: @Ubunkun さん、自己解決した場合でも、その解決方法は質問内に追記するのではなく、回答として投稿してください。またその回答には承認の操作をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

storyboard上のconstraintsが効いていました。constraintsを削除して解決しました。